# Not able to install a library in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

I am new to Heroku. I tried installing the library `logging` by specifying in the `requirements.txt` file and even using the web console, both times it returned with this error:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_pd86m9k/logging/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-_pd86m9k/logging/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-zn83hw3w
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-_pd86m9k/logging/
    Complete output (48 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-zn83hw3w/logging.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-zn83hw3w/logging.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-zn83hw3w/logging.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-zn83hw3w/logging.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-zn83hw3w/logging.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-_pd86m9k/logging/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        setup(name = "logging",
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 297, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 304, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 535, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 571, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/distutils/command/sdist.py", line 226, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_python()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 135, in _add_defaults_python
        build_py = self.get_finalized_command('build_py')
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/distutils/cmd.py", line 298, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj = self.distribution.get_command_obj(command, create)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/distutils/dist.py", line 857, in get_command_obj
        klass = self.get_command_class(command)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 764, in get_command_class
        self.cmdclass[command] = cmdclass = ep.load()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2462, in load
        return self.resolve()
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2468, in resolve
        module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 16, in <module>
        from setuptools.lib2to3_ex import Mixin2to3
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/lib2to3_ex.py", line 13, in <module>
        from lib2to3.refactor import RefactoringTool, get_fixers_from_package
      File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/refactor.py", line 19, in <module>
        import logging
      File "/tmp/pip-install-_pd86m9k/logging/logging/__init__.py", line 618
        raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                 ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea where am I going wrong or what I should do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`logging` module on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/logging/#history) is *ancient*, having been most recently updated in June, 2013. The specific error you're seeing is due to the old tuple syntax for `except` which was [removed in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#changed-syntax).

You are probably just looking for [the `logging` module](https://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) that [has been included with Python since version 2.3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html). Since it is part of the standard library you don't need to do anything to install it.

Remove it from your `requirements.txt`, commit, and redeploy.